# get creditmemo Pdf with template

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo

I manage to obtain the creditmemos in pdf format via this code (for a webservice)

```
$result = array();
//.....
//....

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id); // my store id

$CreditMemo = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $creditmemo_id))
        ->load();
if ($CreditMemo->getSize() > 0) {
  $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_Creditmemo')->getPdf($CreditMemo);
  if ($pdf) {
    $file = $pdf->render(); // get the pdf content
    $result['file'] = base64_encode($file); // convert it to 64
  }
}

return $result; //return result in soap
```

But it doesnt apply the same template as in the frontend.

I use a similar code to generate PDF invoices and do not encounter this problem....

Do you know how to define the template for creditmemos ?

Thanks;

Answer (score 0):

Finally the site had an SNMM module (Auit).
By using it I was able to get the file with the right template

```
 $creditMemos = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_collection');
 $creditMemos->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $creditmemo_id);
 $creditMemos->load();

 foreach ($creditMemos as $C) {
    $pdf = Mage::getModel('auit_pdf/creditmemo')->getPdf(array($C));

    //.... etc...
```